# Filter & display Custom Post Type posts by their assigned catagories?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I have a Custom Post Type called 'Services', *it's slug is called 'services'.* And as displayed in this image, they all have their own assigned categories.

### [image: My 'Services' post type with categories.]

How do I go about writing a WP_Query/loop that displays the titles of all 'Services' with the category 'Face'? *(With a hyperlink to their respective pages also.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code that will achieve the result you want

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'category'    => 'Face',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    ----Here will be your html in which format you want to display your title-----
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
  <?php endwhile; 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Amazing, worked like a charm & super simple also. Thanks for everything! :)

Comment: Hi @raju_eww would you know how I should use this code if I want to duplicate it rougly seven times over but with each one having a different category?

Comment: I alredy answer your newly asked question please review it and marked as helpful if it helps so it will be helpful for other